# Environment variables are nil in Rails app (can't connect to Google Drive)

Tags: learn-ruby-on-rails

Working with the book [Learn Ruby on Rails](http://learn-rails.com/learn-ruby-on-rails.html), I'm stuck on the section of the tutorial where you connect to Google Drive to save the form submission to a spreadsheet.

I'm not able to authenticate w/ Google because `Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_username` and `Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_password` are nil. More specifically, it seems like my rails app isn't seeing any of my environment variables.

I've verified that the variables are set properly:

```
ynkwinl-ujurvt0:learn-rails katie$ printenv | grep GMAIL_USERNAME
GMAIL_USERNAME=kjXXXXXX@gmail.com
```

And from the console:

```
learn-rails :001 > ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"]
 => "kjXXXXXX@gmail.com"
```

But trying to access it via Rails:

```
learn-rails :001 > Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_username
 => nil
```

The relevant line of secrets.yml:

```
email_provider_username: <%= ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"] %>
```

I've been stuck on this for an hour and can't find an answer (the previous question on this topic covered a slightly different scenario).

I've worked around it by hard coding my username/password into the `secrets.yml` file, but I'd like to understand what's going on for future reference.

Full 'secrets.yml' file for reference:

```
development:

  email_provider_username: <%= ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"] %>
  email_provider_password: <%= ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"] %>
  domain_name: example.com
  mailchimp_api_key: <%= ENV["MAILCHIMP_API_KEY"] %>
  mailchimp_list_id: <%= ENV["MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID"] %>
  owner_email: <%= ENV["OWNER_EMAIL"] %>
  secret_key_base: very_long_random_string

test:
  secret_key_base: very_long_random_string

# Do not keep production secrets in the repository,
# instead read values from the environment.
production:
  email_provider_username: <%= ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"] %>
  email_provider_password: <%= ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"] %>
  domain_name: <%= ENV["DOMAIN_NAME"] %>
  mailchimp_api_key: <%= ENV["MAILCHIMP_API_KEY"] %> 
  mailchimp_list_id: <%= ENV["MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID"] %> 
  owner_email: <%= ENV["OWNER_EMAIL"] %>
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

Comment: Can you attach a content of secrets.yml?

Comment: Added to original post.

Comment: Nothing comes into mind. The only test env does not have those keys. Can you execute `Rails.env` in your rails console to ensure, that you are loading correct environment?

Comment: 2.2.0 :001 > Rails.env
 => "development"

Comment: Having the same issue, any resolution on this?

Answer (score 8):

I had this problem and it was caused by [spring](https://github.com/rails/spring) running the server in the background even when I quit the server in the terminal.

If this is the cause in your case, you can fix it by running `spring stop`.

Comment: Running `spring stop` in my Terminal (not rails console) works. Thanks!

Comment: you're a savior! I think rubymine started spring for me for whatever reason... i'm not even using it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Rails.application.secrets['email_provider_username']
```